# Get event: "focus out" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, input

As I wrote in title I need to catch event: focus out. In fack I am doing it in change EventListener, but it have blind-spot.
...
When I don't change text and then I lose focus on input: change EventListener isn't working (becouse I didn't change text).

```
var menage_ul=function(ev, label, value)
{
    if(value!=null) //if it is 'click' or 'keyup'
    {
        var names_to_show=user_names.filter(function(name){
            return name.indexOf(value)==0;
        });
        create_ul(label, names_to_show);
    }
    else if(value===null)//if it is 'change'
    {
        create_ul(label, new Array());
    }
    else//if it is 'keypress'
    {
        if(ev.which===13)//if pressed enter
        {
            if(label.className==='save_as')
            {
                save_as();
            }
            else if(label.className==='open')
            {
                open();
            }
            else{}
        }
    }
};

input.addEventListener('click', function(ev){menage_ul(ev, label, input.value);}, false);
input.addEventListener('keyup', function(ev){menage_ul(ev, label, input.value);}, false);
input.addEventListener('change', function(ev){menage_ul(ev, label, null);}, false);
input.addEventListener('keypress', function(ev){menage_ul(ev, label);}, false);
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you try this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/tuG33/1/

Comment: @AravindS  I missed 'focusout' when I was looking for anserw. Thanks for help :)

Comment: happy to help... I added it as answer...so others will be benefited. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `input.addEventListener('focusout', handler, false);`..here goes the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Aravi/yur3gtb9/